# Adding doubles from a file to get total in java

Tags: java, file, double, addition

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Jacob   Andrews 8159    Rose    Ct  Mill City   OR  97322   5552127879  64.00
Ryan    Perkins 7546    Prince  Ave Las Vegas   NV  87126   5553451989  13.00
Joshua  Gilbert 9278    Monroe  Dr  Corvallis   CA  97330   5552832656  95.00
Miles   Crain   4578    Chester Dr  Corvallis   OR  97331   5552345678  1544.00
Butch   Cassidy 5498    Sutton  Pl  Gresham AZ  97380   5416565797  1798.56
Perry   Winkle  8185    Shaver  Ave Las Vegas   NV  87126   5553812346  195.66
```

everything is separated by tabs.

My while loop is like this:

```
       while(fileScan.hasNextLine())
        {
           String currentLine = fileScan.nextLine();
           String[]dataSet = currentLine.split("\t");

           String firstName = dataSet[0];
           String lastName = dataSet[1];
           String Address = dataSet[2] +(' ');
           Address += dataSet[3] +(' ');
           Address += dataSet[4];
           String city = dataSet[5];
           String state = dataSet[6];
           String zip = dataSet[7];
           String phone = dataSet[8];
           String donation = dataSet[9];
           int ZIP = Integer.parseInt(zip);
           Double Donation = Double.parseDouble(donation);
```

As you can see I made the donation read as a double, my question is how do I get the donation total? I need to write the code to add up and get the total donations but cannot figure it out. Any advice would be great.

Comment: If the donations are money amounts, consider using BigDecimal instead of double to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop:

```
double totalDonation = 0.0;
```

Inside the loop, at the end:

```
totalDonation += Donation;
```

Comment: oh my word I feel so stupid! I kept trying this but I was declaring the variable in the loop can't believe I overlooked that. You are awesome thanks for your help!